# how many technologies are there used in magento 2?

Tags: magento2

When I started to learn Magento 2 architecture and its working flow, I found many more sub-technologies they had implemented into M2 core than PHP, prototypeJs, CSS, jQuery & html.

E.g.

- nodeJs
- KnowkoutJs
- CSS pre-processor – LESS
- JavaScript Task Runner – Grunt
- M2 framework – Composition of Zend Framework
- Bootstrap composer
- ui_component
- Dependency Injection
- requireJs
- Asynchronous Module Definition (AMD) & SHIM
- PHP Standard Recommendations (PSR)
- PHP 5.5 to 7 [Traits, ]
- Redis – Key Value Cache Storage Engine
- Varnish 4.0 HTTP accelerator
- CSS3
- HTML5
- Xdebug – Debugger and Profiler Tool for PHP
- Command Line Tool
- Reflection
- Interception
- phpunit
- symfony

Can any one please list all the sub-technologies list with best tutorial link of that.

By the way, I will find the tutorial from search engine. I just need to know the list.

Comment: We trying to keep this post updated with all new stuff what we find :) https://firebearstudio.com/blog/magento-2-technology-stack.html

Answer (score 1):

For most of technologies exists site with documentation that you can use.

Also nodeJs, LESS, Grunt, Varnish, redis, Xdebug, symfony is optional, and don't have direct relation to Magento2.

And Magento2 have [official documentation](http://devdocs.magento.com/) for UI Components, DI, Plugins.

Comment: Hi Kandy, I has asked this question as per the backend developer as well as front-end developer view. We have got useful information from m2 official document. Still we need to know the technologies used by this new m2.